# Problems running Anaconda

Tags: python, anaconda

I'm trying tu run Anaconda using `anaconda-navigator` command and I have the following error (English and Spanish together):

`2021-11-10 10:25:04,304 - WARNING linux_scaling.get_primary_monitor_name:59 Can't detect primary monitor.`

`Violación de segmento ('core' generado)`

After uninstall my second screen monitor I have only this error message:

`Violación de segmento ('core' generado)`

I have tried updating my Anaconda installation, uninstall and reinstall, updating Spyder and nothing succeed.

Has anyone any idea of what is happening?

Thanks a lot for your time.